# Angular 15: Migrating require.context to import.meta.webpackContext is causing this error: {}.webpackContext is not a function

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I've recently upgraded Angular 14 to 15 and with it there was issues with require.context.

Without getting into that - I've used import.meta.webpackContext which is meant to be the ESM equivalent to the former where it returns the same requireContext object.

However after using the new function I'm getting this error:
`{}.webpackContext is not a function`

```
function importAll(r: __WebpackModuleApi.RequireContext) {
  r.keys().forEach((key: string) => (cache[key] = r(key)));
}

const ESM_CONFIG = {
  recursive: true,
  regExp: /\.[j|t]s$/,
  exclude: /spec\.[j|t]s$/,
};

if (import.meta.webpackContext) {
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./services/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./components/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./directives/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./filters/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./native-extensions/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./prototypes/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./views/', ESM_CONFIG));
}
```

Comment: as a side note: when I used require.context I got 

__webpack_require__(...).context is not a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating from require.context to import.meta.webpackContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75028454/migrating-from-require-context-to-import-meta-webpackcontext)