# Migrating from require.context to import.meta.webpackContext

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am trying to migrate my Vue PWA to ESM, replacing all `require` by `import`.

But replacing `require.context` by [`import.meta.webpackContext`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#importmetawebpackcontext) gives me the following warning at compile-time:

> Critical dependency: Accessing import.meta directly is unsupported
> (only property access is supported)

And then the following error at run-time:

> Uncaught TypeError: {}.webpackContext is not a function

The way I use it is the following:

```
const icons = import.meta.webpackContext('../components/icon', false, /icon.*\.vue/);
```

I use webpack 5.75.0

I guess this is the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74863795/angular-15-migrating-require-context-to-import-meta-webpackcontext-is-causing-t) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74876632/import-meta-webpackcontext-returns-undefined-but-still-manages-to-get-into-an-if).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error from webpack is misleading, the issue comes from the fact that `import.meta.webpackContext` has [other arguments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#importmetawebpackcontext):

```
(
  request: string,
  options?: {
    recursive?: boolean;
    regExp?: RegExp;
    include?: RegExp;
    exclude?: RegExp;
    preload?: boolean | number;
    prefetch?: boolean | number;
    chunkName?: string;
    exports?: string | string[][];
    mode?: 'sync' | 'eager' | 'weak' | 'lazy' | 'lazy-once';
  }
) => webpack.Context;
```

So in my case I switched to the following to make it work:

```
const icons = import.meta.webpackContext('../components/icon', {recursive: false, regExp: /icon.*\.vue/});
```